# React render component conditionally inside parent component on route click

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-functional-component

I'm trying to render a component conditionally inside a wrapper component from my main menu. I'm new to React, I was programming in Vue. Maybe this is why I can't find a "react solution" to my problem.

I have a navigation menu rendered from an array like this:

```
export default {
  {
    id: "home",
    title: "Inicio",
    navLink: "/home"
  
  },
  {
    id: "wrappercomponent",
    title: "Wrapper Component",
    children: [
      {
        id: "childcomponent1",
        title: "Child component 1",
        navLink: "/wrappercomponent/childcomponent1"
      },
      {
        id: "childcomponent2",
        title: "Child component 2",
        navLink: "/wrappercomponent/childcomponent2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My routes are something like this:

```
const Routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    index: true,
    element: <Navigate replace to={DefaultRoute} />
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    element: <Home />
  },
  {
    path: '/wrappercomponent',
    element: <WrapperComp />
  }
  // and so on (this is an example)
}
```

What I need in my menu component is something like this:

```
import ComponentExtra from './componentextra'
import ComponentData from './componentdata'

const WrapperComp = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <ComponentExtra />
      </div>
      <div>
        <ComponentData />
      </div>
      <div>
        {/* I need to render here childcomponent1 or childcomponent2 components according to menu link clicked */}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default WrapperComp
```

I think I'm still "thinking in Vue" and I'm not able to find a solution despite hours of searching the web on how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to add a dynamic route, something like, `/menu/:sub-menu#` and then check in the `Menu` component above what placeholder sub-menu is and render the specific subcomponent/menu based on that. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Are you just trying to render "sub"-menu components? Is that it? I don't see what routing has to do with this. This seems like something Material-ui and countless other UI component libraries have solved already. Please explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I’m sorry Drew, but I don’t know what a ui has to do with my question. I need to click in submenu1 (in my navigation menu) and render in comoonent menu (where the comment line is) the component Submenu1.  And clicking submenu2, render component Submenu2 in the exact same place where submenu1 was. In vue is a router-view

Comment: Perhaps something is lost in translation here. Are the menus/submenus *not* the UI you are trying to render? What submenus are you trying to render? What is stopping you from rendering the submenu components there where the comment is? Please include all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using as part of your [mcve].

Comment: I don’t know how to do it, if it’s well said, dynamically. I don’t know how to click on my navigation link to /wrappercomponent/childcomponent1 and render <Childcomponent1 /> where the commented line is. Same with component2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly now, you want to conditionally render different components into the `div` element in `WrapperComp` based on a matched sub-route.

Render an `Outlet` component there and add nested routes to the `"/wrappercomponent"` route so they render their `element` content into the `Outlet` where you want the content.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import ComponentExtra from './componentextra'
import ComponentData from './componentdata'

const WrapperComp = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <ComponentExtra />
      </div>
      <div>
        <ComponentData />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

...

```
const routesConfig = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Navigate replace to={defaultRoute} />
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    element: <Home />
  },
  {
    path: '/wrappercomponent',
    element: <WrapperComp />,
    children: [
      { path: "childcomponent1", element: <Childcomponent1 /> },
      { path: "childcomponent2", element: <Childcomponent2 /> },
    ],
  },
  ...
};
```

[image: Edit react-render-component-conditionally-inside-parent-component-on-route-click]

[image]